# How can I find number of jobs running by user in Haddop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I would like to know number of jobs running in Hadoop without any UI application, Actually I'm more interested in table some kind of query.

Answer (score 2):

you can call the

- REST API https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html
- command line "yarn application"  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html

and extract all needed information

Comment: is there any table ?

Comment: No, there is notable :)